# Using ssh with certificate-based authentication

Tags: ssh, certificates

I'm trying to do a ssh connection based on certificates. I'm following [this](https://ef.gy/hardening-ssh) guide. If you look at it there is a step where I have to put line

```
@cert-authority *.example.com contents-of-public-key-file
```

in file

```
~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

However, my public key file looks like:

```
ssh-rsa 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 CA key for spsi
```

And furthermore this doesn't match the syntax of known_hosts which has lines of the form:

```
|1|YFa0r2/C0Q2ENwoA3zfBtvVopWQ=|eo4lCYYLUr/54pD+Wmr25XESwuM= ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAJtrmDPnRNMEANyxlvkz1I0Hv3RLGdjWr0frJgr+wQmY0MnwKO+QDzhklq
```

Do you have a clear way of doing this in the command line rather than editing manually the file? Also, what is the idea of this whole scheme? What is the difference between a certificate approach and a public/private key system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And furthermore this doesn't match the syntax of known_hosts which has lines of the form:

This does not matter. One of them is hashed (Ubuntu default) and you are using non-hashed version. They can coexist next to each other without any problem. Just do as requested:

```
@cert-authority *.example.com ssh-rsa [...base64blob...] CA key for spsi
```

> Do you have a clear way of doing this in the command line rather than editing manually the file?

Do it manually. There is no command-line way of doing that unless you will write some script.

> Also, what is the idea of this whole scheme? What is the difference between a certificate approach and a public/private key system?

With Certificates you will have only single line in your known hosts, that will verify all servers hosts keys that are signed by this CA. And you will never get asked to verify hosts keys for these hosts (which is the most annoying feature of SSH).